# SQLite - return rows where a column contains duplicate substring

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

Our naming convention for workstations ends in the serial number of device.  I am trying to get a list of workstations in a SQLite database that have been renamed/re-imaged and are now duplicated so the old device can be removed. Sometimes, the re-imaged device will have the same name as it did before.  The key is having the same serial number.  My SQL skills aren't up to the task and I have only found similar questions that don't quite get me what I need.

Example data   (serial numbers are random string of letters and digits, but always the same length.  The - is always in the same location)

Assets

| Hostname | LastSeen |
| --- | --- |
| usera-serial042 | 2023/09/22 |
| usera-serial042 | 2023/10/29 |
| userc-serial222 | 2023/10/29 |
| userd-serial312 | 2023/10/30 |
| usere-serial312 | 2023/10/11 |
| userf-serial822 | 2023/10/11 |
| userg-serial219 | 2023/10/11 |

I would like the results to be

```
usera-serial042  2023/09/22 
usera-serial042  2023/10/29
userd-serial312  2023/10/30 
usere-serial312  2023/10/11
```

I can extract the serial number using:

```
SUBSTR(hostname, (INSTR(hostname, '-')+1), (LENGTH(hostname)-INSTR(hostname, '-')))
```

I can get a list of all duplicate serial numbers using

```
select SUBSTR(hostname, (INSTR(hostname, '-')+1), (LENGTH(hostname)-INSTR(hostname, '-'))) as serial, count(*) 
from assets 
group by serial 
having count(*) > 1
```

But I can't get figure out how to return the entire list of hostnames where there are duplicate serials.

I would greatly appreciate the help!

Thanks!

Comment: @empthy Do a search that grabs the LastSeen if that value matches any other LastSeen send that data to a new column or another table. You can create a new table in a DB table that has already been created Once you have the new table populated take a look at the ID and write a delete query where ID equals here are some useful SQL command I used for a sort of similar issue ALTER TABLE TxData ADD NxData INTEGER
UPDATE TxData SET NxData = txSearchMonth
ALTER TABLE TxData DROP COLUMN txSearchMonth
ALTER TABLE TxData RENAME COLUMN NxData to txSearchMonth
OR use DB Browser look at Data & delete

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to utilise the [**`group_concat`**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#group_concat) aggregate function which could provide a CSV of the hostnames (and lastseen's if required)

e.g.

```
select SUBSTR(hostname, (INSTR(hostname, '-')+1), (LENGTH(hostname)-INSTR(hostname, '-'))) as serial, count(*)
    ,group_concat(hostname) AS serial_csv
    /* lastseens delimited with ~ */
    , group_concat(lastseen,'~') AS dlm_lastseenlist
from assets 
group by serial 
having count(*) > 1;
```

To demonstrate (with additional data to show a 3rd with 3 duplicates):-

```
/* just in case Cleanup */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS assets;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS assets (hostname TEXT, lastseen TEXT);
INSERT INTO assets VALUES

    ('usera-serial042','2023/09/22')
    ,('usera-serial042','2023/10/29')
    ,('userc-serial222','2023/10/29')
    ,('userd-serial312','2023/10/30')
    ,('usere-serial312','2023/10/11')
    ,('userf-serial822','2023/10/11')
    ,('userg-serial219','2023/10/11')
    /* added for demo */
    ,('userx-serial111','2023/10/01')
    ,('userxy-serial111','2023/10/11')
    ,('userz-serial111','2023/10/21')
    
;
select SUBSTR(hostname, (INSTR(hostname, '-')+1), (LENGTH(hostname)-INSTR(hostname, '-'))) as serial, count(*)
    ,group_concat(hostname) AS serial_csv
    /* lastseens delimited with ~ */
    , group_concat(lastseen,'~') AS dlm_lastseenlist
from assets 
group by serial 
having count(*) > 1;
/* Cleanup Demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS assets;
```

resulting in:-

[image]

[SQLFiddle of the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/18077)

If you wanted just the serial part then you could use `group_concat(SUBSTR(hostname, (INSTR(hostname, '-')+1), (LENGTH(hostname)-INSTR(hostname, '-'))))`

If you wanted a list of hostnames and lastseens  that are only duplicates then you could use:-

```
WITH cte_duplicates AS (
    select SUBSTR(hostname, (INSTR(hostname, '-')+1), (LENGTH(hostname)-INSTR(hostname, '-'))) as serial, count(*)
    from assets 
    group by serial 
    having count(*) > 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM assets 
WHERE SUBSTR(hostname, (INSTR(hostname, '-')+1), (LENGTH(hostname)-INSTR(hostname, '-'))) IN (select serial FROM cte_duplicates);
```

Which, using the data above, would result in:-

[image]

- note that `having count(*)` is sufficient i.e. no need for the output column as per `, count(*)`